# ¿Cómo sumar en SQL pero reiniciar si la columna es 0?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tengo la siguiente tabla de ejemplo:

```
CLI_ID  A2015   A2016   A2017   A2018   A2019   A2020   TOTAL
444765   0       0       1       0       1       1       3
577414   1       0       0       1       0       1       3
```

Si sumo de A2015 a A 2020 el resultado es de 3, ¿cierto?
pero necesito en el cliente 444765 debe ser 2 debido a que hubo una interrupción en los años y  no fue seguido y en el cliente 577414 1, por el mismo motivo.

¿Alguna idea?

Espero obtener:

```
CLI_ID  A2015   A2016   A2017   A2018   A2019   A2020   TOTAL
444765   0       0       1       0       1       1       2
577414   1       0       0       1       0       1       1
```

Probado: (logicamente me suma pero no lo que necesito)

```
SELECT C.CLI_ID, (... columas del 2015 al 2020)
SUM(A10.FechaVencimiento_YEAR + A11.FechaVencimiento_YEAR + A12.FechaVencimiento_YEAR + A13.FechaVencimiento_YEAR + A14.FechaVencimiento_YEAR + A15.FechaVencimiento_YEAR + A16.FechaVencimiento_YEAR + A17.FechaVencimiento_YEAR + A18.FechaVencimiento_YEAR + A19.FechaVencimiento_YEAR + A20.FechaVencimiento_YEAR) AS TOTAL
FROM CLIENTES AS C
GROUP BY C.CLI_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que solo trabajas con `1` y `0`, se puede lograr si haces la operacion `[(n + (n+1))* (n+1)]` (asi con todas las columnas), no se si me explico bien, pero te dejo la query

```
SELECT CLI_ID, A2015, A2016, A2017, A2018, A2019, A2020 , 
(((((((((A2015 + A2016) * A2016 ) + A2017) * A2017) + A2018) * A2018) + A2019) * A2019) + A2020) * A2020  AS TOTAL
FROM CLIENTES
```

[image: Resultado de la consulta]

---

PD: He observado que en tu query hay A11, A12, ... , creo que estas usando varias referencias a la misma tabla, considera mejorar la consulta (tal vez usando un pivot), **yo solo te he apoyado en resolver el tema de la suma**, podrias abrir otra pregunta para que te ayuden con tu query a nivel mas general.

Saludos

Comment: Saludos @Jorge Muñoz Feliciano, no logro comprender aun tu consulta, pero me estoy peleando haber que es lo que esta haciendo, quiero comprenderla a nivel de lógica. en cuanto al pivot de la tabla termina siendo muy cargada pues casi que por obligación primero debo consultar por cada año si existe o no el producto y esta consulta por año se repite en la misma tabla, tal y como tu dices, en un inicio le agregué el pivot, pero me tira constantes deadlocks. muchas gracias por tus sugerencias!

Comment: Para aclarar las dudas sobre la lógica, es sumar el siguiente resultado y luego multiplicarlo por ese mismo, con una prueba de escritorio talvez sea mas fácil explicarlo:

Comment: Haz el calculo por cada año siguiendo este caso:  

`(A2015 + A2016) * A2016` y el resultado lo usas para el siguiente año

Comment: Ahhh ya ya entendí, pero no funcionó pues si el año es 2020 y está en o entonces "resetea" todo de nuevo y queda en 0 el total.

Comment: Yo habia entendio que el 0 reseteaba, pero si lo que quieres es obtener el mismo resultado pero sin que salga cero deberas recorrerlo desde atras y contar hasta que encuentres un 0 , pero deberas estar poniendo demasiados if. Otra opcion es unirlos como varchar, obtener el indice del ultimo cero y obtener len() de los caracteres de la derecha ( pero si el cero es el ultimo caracter,  tomar los valores desde el penultimo 0 hasta el ultimo 0). Espero que al menos te pueda acercar a la solucion. Suerte

Comment: Es que hay es donde me he quemado la cabeza pensando como lo hago, pues el 0 puede estar en cualquier año, la intención es ver cuantos años lleva el cliente pero si tuvo interrupción, se penaliza reseteando el conteo y vuelve a empezar.